# Allow URLs in to website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have couple of URLs that I need to allow to access before page load and remaining URLs will be redirected.

```
expample: If user trying to access these urls they will be allowed and 
   other urls will be redirected to google.com (example)

http://mysite.com/site/Dept/IT
http://mysite.com/site/Dept/IT/ITWS
http://mysite.com/site/dept/ce
http://mysite.com/site/dept/mkt
http://mysite.com/site/teams/dgt
http://mysite.com/site/teams/mm
```

How can do this in jQuery? Making arraylist for URL and check against arraylist and allow them.

Comment: This is pretty easy to do in PHP if you're not opposed to using PHP for your webpage..

Comment: What if I have JavaScript turned off?

Comment: @Wex: It is asp.net masterpage.

Comment: @Rocket: jQuery still works right.

Comment: @James123: jQuery is not its own language, it is a JavaScript library.  Therefore, no JavaScript, no jQuery.

Comment: then how to handle this?

Comment: This should be handled at the server level, not the application level. Read up on the config options for whatever server you are using. Look for redirection or URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use this for external URL's.](http://jsfiddle.net/dsXh9/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).attr("href").match("^http://yoursite.com.*$"))
        {
            if (!confirm("Do you realy want to leave this site?"))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you realy want to reject special URL's on your server I would realy suggest you to do it serverside.

Answer (score 2):

You can load Javascript snippet on every page and it will redirect the user if the current page's url doesn't match any of these.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urls = ["http://mysite.com/site/Dept/IT",
              "http://mysite.com/site/Dept/IT/ITWS",
              "http://mysite.com/site/dept/ce",
              "http://mysite.com/site/dept/mkt",
              "http://mysite.com/site/teams/dgt",
              "http://mysite.com/site/teams/mm"];
    if ($.inArray(document.location.href, urls) == -1) {
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
});
```