# Find in URL string from Array of values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find array values in URL string? check the condition If requested URL contains array values then pass condition otherwise redirect to google.com

example

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var urls = ["/dept/ce/",
                      "/dept/cs",
                      "/dept/career",
                      "/dept/it",
                      "/dept/mkt/",
                      "/dept/Membership/"
                      , "/dept/pr"
                      , "/dept/PS"
                      , "/dept/ta"
                      , "/dept/wc"
                      , "/dept/PubsProducts"
                      , "_layouts/settings.aspx"
                      ,"/_catalogs/masterpage/"];

       //If document.location.href = "http://localhost/dept/ce/default.aspx" 
       //And Array has "/dept/ce" values
       //Now check document.location.href against array values, if    
      //document.location.href contains array values then pass condition otherwise 
      //else condition 
    });
```

How to do this?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry, hard to understand your question. could you rephrase?

Comment: I don't see exactly what you're trying to do, are you just trying to see if any of the url string values are contained within the current url?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just rephrased this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow URLs in to website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436443/allow-urls-in-to-website)

Comment: @Rocket by the same person even

Comment: @Rocket, Eonansda: The requirement was changed. So That post functionality was not working. I tried different things also.

Comment: @James123: This really isn't something that should be done with JavaScript.  What if I have JavaScript turned off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to do something, IF the current location URL contains any of the strings in your array. Since you are using jQuery already, I recommend jQuery.grep.

Example:

```
if ($.grep(urls, function(str) { return location.href.indexOf(str) > -1; }).length > 0) {
  // do one thing
} else {
  // do another thing
}
```

Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/